# Compiling by hand doesn't work because of missing Cygwin

Tags: c, compilation, cygwin, mingw

I used to create and compile C programs with Codeblocks. I wanted to compile it by hand, so I tried to do it with a Makefile. However it seems that I am missing an important detail, because when I execute the program, it throws me an error that I never had when compiling with Codeblocks:

["...cygwin1.dll is missing from your computer..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttrKf.png)

I watched and studied the compilation code [seen in Codeblocks when running the "compile" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JHYO.png):

```
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g -I"D:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\SDL2\x32\include" -c "C:\Users\nounoursnoir\Desktop\dev\C\exercices\SDL Tower Defense\main.c" -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe -L"D:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\SDL2\x32\lib" -o "bin\Debug\SDL Tower Defense.exe" obj\Debug\main.o  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image  "D:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libmingw32.a" "D:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\SDL2\x32\lib\libSDL2main.a" "D:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\SDL2\x32\lib\libSDL2.dll.a" "D:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\SDL2\x32\lib\libSDL2_image.dll.a"
Output file is bin\Debug\SDL Tower Defense.exe with size 43.42 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

The best I could do to make a similar compilation was this Makefile:

```
FLAGS=-Wall -g
I=-I/d/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/CodeBlocks/SDL2/x32/include
L1=-L/d/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/CodeBlocks/SDL2/x32/lib
L2=-L/d/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib
l=-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
l1="D:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libmingw32.a"
l2="D:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\SDL2\x32\lib\libSDL2main.a"
l3="D:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\SDL2\x32\lib\libSDL2.dll.a"
l4="D:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\SDL2\x32\lib\libSDL2_image.dll.a"
CFROM="C:\Users\nounoursnoir\Desktop\dev\C\exercices\SDL Tower Defense\main.c"
OBJTO="obj\Debug\main.o"
EXETO="bin\Debug\SDL Tower Defense.exe"

main: main.o
    gcc $(L1) $(L2) -o $(EXETO) $(OBJTO) $(l) $(l1) $(l2) $(l3) $(l4)

main.o: main.c
    gcc $(FLAGS) $(I) -c $(CFROM) -o $(OBJTO)
```

When running the command `make` and double-clicking the produced executable's icon, the error described above happens, and I don't understand why, what is happening and how to fix it. I need help to understand this.

You may take note that when running the executable from the shell Babun, it works fine: `./bin/Debug/SDL\ Tower\ Defense.exe` (needed libraries were moved in ./bin/Debug in order to make it work).

Plus, to me, Cygwin seems to be installed on my machine and an environment PATH variable points to its location: `C:\Users\nounoursnoir\.babun\cygwin`. I don't see it could be missing anything.

Comment: If you're using a Cygwin compiler (i.e. `gcc` in your `PATH`), you'll have trouble when mixing it with MinGW stuff. Instead, set `CC` in your makefile to `D:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\mingw32-gcc.exe` (or wherever that file is located in the CodeBlocks directory) and replace `gcc` in your rules with `$(CC)`. Alternatively, you might try adding `-mno-cygwin` to your rules. I'm not sure if that switch still works or not, but long ago it compiled a native MinGW version without the need for the `cygwin1.dll`.

Comment: putting `D:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\mingw32-gcc.exe` as the command to be used results in an error: `command not found`, even though the file exists and the path is correct... As for `-mno-cygwin`, it is not recognized as a command and i can't find anything (literraly) on Google.

Comment: That's my fault. Change the forward slashes to backslashes (`D:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/mingw32-gcc.exe`), and it should at least get you a bit further if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: mingw32's gcc didn't work but your messages helped me understand what was going on. For now I simply put the shared library `cygwin1.dll` in the project's directory and it works. But it means that I still use cygwin and mingw at the same time, which I suppose is not ideal. I will experiment and document myself and should be able to make a hand compilation with only mingw (or only cygwin). thank you for your help